# I want to change dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello~ help me please!!

I have a dataframe like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zof6b.png)

```
  a  b
1 1  q
2 3  w
3 2  e
4 3  e
5 3  q
6 2  w
7 1  e
8 3  e
9 2  q
```

but, I want to make it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zof6b.png)

```
  q w e
1 1   1
2 1 1 1
3 1 1 2
```

What I have to in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `table` to get the frequency

```
table(df1)
#     b
#a    e q w
#   1 1 1 0
#   2 1 1 1 
#   3 2 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want the result to be in the form of a data frame. What should I do?

Comment: YOu can do `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1))`